# IModelBinder or IOC in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ioc-container

While Scott Hanselman performed an excellent demonstration of the use of IModelBinder in 
“[IPrincipal (User) ModelBinder in ASP.NET MVC for easier testing](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IPrincipalUserModelBinderInASPNETMVCForEasierTesting.aspx)” he felt compelled to make this rather defensive comment:

> Yes, I realize I could use an IoC container for this also.

Did he mean that he could have used IOC *instead of* IModelBinder or is he saying that we should use IModelBinder *with* IOC? With the understanding that many, many things can be done with a general-purpose programming language (now I’m getting defensive) what is actually done in real-world scenarios? For example, a project like [KiGG](http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg) does not appear to be using IModelBinder at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, in my project I have a custom binder that does something like this (I use it with ViewModel like shown [here](http://sprokhorenko.blogspot.com/2009/09/my-custom-aspnet-mvc-entity-binding.html)):

```
public interface IEntityResolver
{
   object Find(string id);
}

public class PrimaryKeyResolver<T> where T: Entity
{
   public PrimaryKeyResolver(IRepository<T> repository) {}
   public object Find(string id)
   {
      return repository.Get(new Guid(id));
   }
}

public class NameResolver<T> where T: NamedEntity
{
   public NameResolver(IRepository<T> repository) {}
   public object Find(string id)
   {
      return repository.Find(new { Name = id });
   }
}

public class MyBinder: IModelBinder
{
   public override object BindModel()
   {
       var id = ... //get id from context
       var resolverType = typeof(IResolver<>).MakeGenericInterface(typeof(bindingContext.ModelType));
       var resolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(resolverType);
       return resolver.Find(id);
   }
}
```

Now, what are the benefits and why it's about IoC? This helps me to keep my model binder free of entity resolution concerns, preserving Separation of Concerns. What does id means and how we get entity is delegated to resolver. This helps to reuse same IModelBinder for any entity. The only thing I need to do is to provide model resolver if (as shown above) I want to search by name, not by id.

IoC here (I use Service Locator but anyway) helps to find proper resolver and instantiate it. Notice that resolvers accept IRepository, which IoC container passes automatically.

About your specific questions, of course we should use IoC **with** IModelBinder, not without - but you can probably also use IoC to instantiate IModelBinder - this will avoid the need to use ServiceLocator; but I don't know how to intercept MVC creating the binder, and frankly I don't care since I'm happy with Locator.

As for KiGG, I usually suggest not to rely on example projects such as NerdDinner or Oxite (can't tell anything about KiGG) as if they're "good design" references - as far as I see they usually demonstrate technical aspects (i.e. features), not good design.

Comment: Do you recommend any MVC projects with educational source code?

Comment: They're all good and educational, but they teach MVC, not design. For me personally a Jimmy Bogard's blog was a big insight on good techniques: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/ (he's co-author of MVC In Action which uses CodeCampServer as example of source so you may look there; not the perfect example I'd say but still).

Answer (score 0):

I've just added this to codeplex http://mvcunity.codeplex.com/ which might help.
I've also added a sample application, let me know if you have any questions.